# Feel bad about doing something because it affects another?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

How to say you feel bad about doing something because it affects another person?  Does the following line sound correct, "It would be inexcusable with regard to him"?

Comment: First of all, the example line sounds awkward. Perhaps, "He would find it inexcusable," or "That would be inexcusable to him." 

Second, the word "sympathetic" means to be emotionally connected to the plight of another person, so perhaps something like, "He was sympathetic of how the people would be affected.

Comment: Thanks! I guess "That would be inexcusable to him" works. But because this line is supposed to be direct speech by the one who is hesitant to do something, "He was sympathetic..." can't be used.

Comment: Unlike the other comment, I don't find your example sentence very awkward at all. I've heard similar phrasing before and it sounds fine to me. As for its meaning: *Such a situation would be inexcusable insofar as it negatively affects him. (And I don't want to do anything that negatively affects anyone.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay reading the question I think the correct phrase is; "It is inexcusable to me that he is affected in this way". That says that you, expressed as the first person "me" feel badly about how something is affecting another expressed as "he". This as opposed to the person affected finding the situation inexcusable which ScottM has phrased perfectly in the comments.

Comment: Good point. I apparently did not understand the example sentence.

Comment: @ScottM I'm not absolutely certain I have it right either but that's my reading of it, hopefully it helps. English is a terribly slippery language some ways.

Comment: Well, looks like I misunderstood ScottM's comment. Haha! So, I meant to say what Ash guessed: "I" feel badly about how something is affecting "him." Thanks!

Comment: @Malapert No worries, happy to help, I thought ScottM had it until I read the question the third time.